# Is there a word respective to Yahoo as googled is to Google?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, internet

The major search engine Google has a word for searching stuff on their site. (google)

Is there a word like this that would fit for Yahoo? At first I thought "Yahooed" but I don't think that would fit grammar rules.

Comment: Does anyone *Dyson* the carpet today? (As opposed to *hoovering* it.) @Peanut: Why do you think ***to google*** is okay, but ***to yahoo*** wouldn't fit "grammar rules"?

Comment: That's not a grammar rule.  That an idiomatic rule.  Grammar is loose enough to let you sound very much dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Yahooed' definitely could work in most circumstances since most people will most likely know what you are talking about, but it is not as common since google is the more popular search engine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another issue to consider is yahoo already existed in English before search engines came along so "to Yahoo" or "Yahooed" probably collides with that older meaning, at least in my mind.